# Requests repeat several times in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, request, use-effect

I have an array

```
let results = [
   {id: 34},
   {id: 32},
   {id: 35},
]
```

When I use `for each` with `useEffect`, the request sends a lot. It repeats several times, but I only use one place. I wrote `results` in the dependencies, but it did not work. I need the requests send one time for ID

my function

```
 useEffect(() => {
    results.forEach(async (data) => {
      const resp = await axios.get(`https://nehra.az/public/api/product/${data.id}`);
      console.log(resp);
    });
  }, []);
```

My Network

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` is a side-effect to the rendering. The fact that this is triggered several times means that you had several renderings for the component. You will need to either use some property to know whether the requests were already sent, or move this code into a place that's executed exactly once.